# If $\Sigma$ is positive definite with $a'\Sigma a>1$ along $\mathbb{Z}^n\backslash 0$, is $\Sigma-I$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, number-theory, statistics

Is $\Sigma - I$ positive semidefinite if $\Sigma$ is positive definite and $a'\Sigma a>1$ for any nonzero $a\in \mathbb{Z}^d$?

---

This arose from the following: take $\vec{x} :=(x_1,\dots, x_d)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ with the property that any nonzero $a\in \mathbb{Z}^d$ has $\operatorname{var}(a' \vec{x}) > 1$. Does each $x_i$ have a component independent of the rest with  power $\geq 1$?

---

Here is an attempt. For $v\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $n$ large, take $v_n=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{round} nv$. Then for some rational basis $\frac{1}{q}(e_i)_i$ in $\frac{1}{q}\mathbb{Z}^d$, $v'(\Sigma -I)v = \lim_n v_n'(\Sigma-I)v_n=\lim_n \sum_i (e_i'\Sigma e_i/q^2 - 1)\cdot (v_n)_i^2 + \sum_{i\neq j} e_i'\Sigma e_j(v_n)_i(v_n)_j/q^2 $. My hope is some basis $(e_i)_i$ can be chosen so the negative terms in the second sum are handled by the positive term.

Comment: $\Sigma=I$ is a counterexample, isn't it? (Unless you mean *semi*definite)

Comment: I'm still interested if the result is only true for semi-definite matrices, (edited this in). Even so I don't think yours was a counterexample since $I$ has, $(e_i)_i$ the standard basis elements, $e_i'Ie_i=1$, not $>1$ as prescribed for $\Sigma$.

Comment: You have a point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true. Take $\Sigma = \left[\begin{matrix} 100 & 10 \\ 10 & 2\end{matrix}\right].$ Now $\Sigma$ has eigenvalues $0.99,101.01$ and the minimum along nonzero integer vectors $a$ of $a'\Sigma a$ is $2.$ But $\Sigma-I$ is is not positive definite.